# How to align text and emoticon in same line?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm using image mapping for emoticons. When I type ':)' it is converted into its corresponding gif smiley image. But, the problem is the emoticon appears a little upward from text. How can I align the emoticon image and text in same line? I tried using margin-top and padding-top, still its intact. Below is the html code of the message which is sent by Username:

```
<div class="message"><span class="userName">
      Username
    </span>
      : hiii 
    <img class="emoticonimg" src="emoticons/face-smile.png"></img>
</div>
```

This is the JQuery code for converting this :) into an emoticon image:

```
html = html.replace(emotes[emoticon][i], "<img src=\"" + icon_folder + "/face-" + emoticon + ".png\" class=\"emoticonimg\"/>", "g");
```

Comment: did you try using line height for the text?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_img_align

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the css `vertical-align` property.

http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

if the image is taller than the line-height, you can try using negative margins:

```
margin: -3px 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS property `vertical-align` will probably do what you want.

[Example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hKEqy)